# Navigation in the file using streampos?

Tags: c++, file, input, codeblocks, ifstream

I need to navigate in the file loaded with ifstream. Precisely I need to save the place I was before in order to be able to return to this exact place after reading a few lines.
I tried something like that:

```
ifstream baseINTING("base.txt");
streampos position1, position2, position3;

position1 = baseINTING.tellg();
```

Later on I've read a few lines:

```
getline(baseINTING, buffer2);
```

And tried to go back:

```
baseINTING.seekg(position1);
```

But it doesn't work. Could someone help me? I really need that denouement.

This is the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <direct.h>
#include <cstdlib>


using namespace std;



void anyNextOne(ifstream* newFile)
{
    ifstream baseINTING("base.txt");
    int j;

    string  buffer2;
    streampos position1;


    getline(baseINTING, buffer2);
    getline(baseINTING, buffer2);

    position1 = baseINTING.tellg();


    for(j=0; j<5; j++)
    {
        getline(baseINTING, buffer2);

        cout<<buffer2<<endl;
        cout<<position1<<endl;

        baseINTING.seekg(position1);

    }

}
int main()
{
    ifstream one("one.txt");
    anyNextOne(&one);


    return 0;
}
```

And examplary output:

Ingredients (for 4 people)

40

(for 4 people)

40

(for 4 people)

40

(...)

The "base.txt" file content:

```
Easy Pizza Recipe 
Dough:
Ingredients (for 4 people)
•   1 cup of warm water 
•   3 1/2 cups of flour
•   2 tablespoons of olive oil
•   2 teaspoons of honey 
•   1 teaspoon of salt
•   1 teaspoon of yeast 
Method:
1. Put warm water into a bowl. Add salt and honey and mix with a spoon. Add yeast, mix and let it sit for about 10 minutes.
2. add flour and olive oil and start mixing. 
3. Let it sit for about another hour. 
4. Put on some tomato sauce.
5. Put on your pizza topping (some green peppers, mushrooms, ketchup, cheese, sausage, salt and pepper) 
6. Bake the pizza in you oven at 200 C for about 20 to 25 minutes.
```

Comment: I didn't see something wrong in the code you gave, can you provide more of your code? And can you explain how it does not work?

Comment: I've posted it below ;)

Comment: I guess editing your question and embedding that code into it would be more appropriate, else people downvote that. About your ploblem, what is the output of that code, are you saying it doesn't go to same place each time you call seekg()?

Comment: Sorry
Edited already

Comment: I still see no problem in your code that can cause this problem. Can you share  that base.txt if its not too long, or first 5-6 lines of it.

Comment: No problem
Editing the post

Comment: I run exact same code but didn't encounter that wierd behaviour. I know this is not the exact answer for your problem, but if you need to solve this urgently, do that :    put that         baseINTING.seekg(position1);  line at the begining of the loop instead of end of the loop so that it start exactly same place  at each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <direct.h>
#include <cstdlib>


using namespace std;



void anyNextOne(ifstream* newFile)
{
    ifstream baseINTING("base.txt");
    int j;

    string  buffer2;
    streampos position1;


    getline(baseINTING, buffer2);
    getline(baseINTING, buffer2);

    position1 = baseINTING.tellg();


    for(j=0; j<5; j++)
    {
        getline(baseINTING, buffer2);

        cout<<buffer2<<endl;
        cout<<position1<<endl;

        baseINTING.seekg(position1);

    }

}
int main()
{
    ifstream one("one.txt");
    anyNextOne(&one);


    return 0;
}
```